# Fitness acceptance tests failing

Tags: .net, fitnesse

They work in a virgin installation, but not in mine that has a front page and added fixture code.
I've gone through page by page and can't find anything different that should have an affect on the built-in tests.

Running an individual test, like
FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteAuthenticationTests.AlwaysSecureOperation
succeeds.

Running a lower level suite, like
FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteAuthenticationTests
succeeds.

But running the entire suite, FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests, throws exceptions in every test.
I get "0 right, 0 wrong, x exceptions" in most tests.

Most of the exceptions are in teardown.
java.lang.NullPointerException

The setup and teardown for the suite look harmless. That should be the only difference in running as part of the suite or outside.

setup/context.txt

```
!|Import|
|fitnesse.fixtures|

!|SetUp|
```

teardown/context.txt

```
----
|tear down|
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to let this go.
As someone else pointed out, this only affects the java tests and the .NET tests all run fine. It seems like an issue with the java test runner, so I should be unaffected.